# What are the tools to draw arbitrary (imagined) geographical regions similar to Matplotlib's Basemap toolkit?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, graphviz

Matplotlib's Basemap is great for drawing the earth map, but I'd like to draw terrains, seas, islands completely made up. Maybe this is similar to [Graphviz's gvmap](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/gd_1994_2007.html), but I'd like something with more customizations, e.g., controllable texture rendering and colorization.

Comment: You just need to provide shapefiles.

Comment: @tcaswell , you mean providing shapeless to gvmap?

Comment: No, to basemap. See https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/tree/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data for the data that ships with base map.  You just need to provide your data in the same format and it will draw what ever shapes you want.

Comment: OK, that sounds like what I need. Thank you so much!